# Spring security custom successHandler not called

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I create my custom authentication filter, provider and successHandler and they are work except successHandler. I set uo authentication-success-handler-ref but it looks like not called.  In logs is used default SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler. I use spring security 4.2.2 and mitreid openid coennect project. I saw many examples how to set up your custom successHandler but they wasn't work.

My filter

```
@Component("custAuthRequestFilter")
public class custAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_SESSION_KEY = "custSession";

    private String sessionParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_SESSION_KEY;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustAuthenticationFilter.class);

    protected CustAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/custlogin", "POST"));
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {

        if (isCustSession(request)) {
            final CustAuthenticationToken authRequest = getAuthRequest(request);
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication is not possible, CustSession is missing");
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("custAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    private CustAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        final String session = obtainSession(request);

        return new CustAuthenticationToken(session);
    }

    private boolean isCustSession(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getParameter(sessionParameter));
    }

    private String obtainSession(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(sessionParameter);
    }
}
```

My provider

```
@Component("custAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustAuthenticationProvider
        implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    private CoreClient coreClient;

    @Autowired
    private InMemoryRepository db;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        LOG.debug("Get user info by session from core service");

        try {
            final List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            final UserDataMap result = coreClient.getUserDataMap(custToken.getPrincipal().toString());

            return new CustAuthenticationToken(custToken.getPrincipal().toString(), authorities);
        } catch(final Exception exc) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Internal error", exc);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(CustAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

My custom successHandler

```
@Component("custSuccessHandler")
public class CustAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        LOG.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> success handler");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

user-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="io.oidcconnector.auth" />

<security:authentication-manager id="custAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="custAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>


<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />

<security:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/authorize" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/custlogin"  authentication-failure-url="/custlogin?error=failure" authentication-success-handler-ref="custSuccessHandler" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=failure" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationTimeStamper" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="authRequestFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="custAuthRequestFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="DENY" />
    </security:headers>
    <security:csrf />
</security:http>

<mvc:view-controller path="/custlogin" view-name="custlogin" />
```

logs

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - 
Checking match of request : '/custlogin'; against '/custlogin'
DEBUG: io.oidcconnector.auth.CustAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using io.oidcconnector.auth.CUstAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG: io.oidcconnector.auth.CustAuthenticationProvider - Get user info by session from core service
DEBUG: io.oidcconnector.auth.CUstAuthenticationFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: io.oidcconnector.auth.CustAuthenticationToken@441c7a52: Principal: abc; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler - Using default Url: /
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/oidc-connector/'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@441c7a52: Authentication: io.oidcconnector.auth.CUstAuthenticationToken@441c7a52: Principal: abc; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@328f5fdf
```

I have no idea why this not working.

Comment: You don't call your `CustAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class in your 'custAuthenticationFilter ' class. Hence, it is not used for your custom authentication.

Comment: Thanks, now it works!!!! But why set ref is not enough?

Comment: The `ref` is for form  authentication, not for custom authentication.